# getting frame from Youtube video

Tags: android, video, youtube

Is there a way to get frame from Youtube video? I found out that it's possible to download the video, and get frame using `MediaMetadataRetriever`. But it seems not the best solution for me. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
**YouTube thumbnails**
```

YouTube thumbnails can be found in this standard path:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video-id]/[thumbnail-number].jpg

```
[video-id] is the YouTube video ID, e.g. 1sIWez9HAbA.
[thumbnail-number] is the number of the thumbnail of the 4 each video usually has, e.g. 0.
```